# can I install shopify 'app' to user dashboard using node?

Tags: node.js, shopify

**I am a shop owner in shopify . I want to install my shopify app to every user logging into my store.**

Is this the way for me to install my app to user visiting my store ?
Can you verify this is the right steps ?

**The below step 2 is from shopify dev section.**

**Step 2: Generate an installation link"**

If you're authenticating a public app, then skip this step and proceed to step 3.

If you're authenticating a custom app, then you need to generate an installation link. A custom app can interact with the Shopify API on behalf of a single store. The merchant uses the link to go through the OAuth process and install the app on their store.

From the app's page in your Partner Dashboard, click Generate link.
Enter the merchant's myshopify.com domain name. For example, mygreatstore.myshopify.com.
Click Generate link, and then click Generate link to confirm.
Copy the installation link from the Merchant install link section and proceed to step 3.

https://shopify.dev/apps/auth/oauth/getting-started#step-2-generate-an-installation-link

this documentation is not so clear , can you point me on right path ? or it is not possible to automate the app installation ?

Answer (score 0):

Since it your store, do the custom selection App, and use the install link they give you. If you wrote your App up correctly, it will authenticate and store an access token so that the App can do whatever it is you want. All your staf with App permissions can then access the App.